# SQLAlchemy <=> Pydantic relationships field required despite init=False

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I have defined a model with SQLAlchemy that is based on a Base class that inherits from the pydantic datalass.

```
class Base(
    MappedAsDataclass,
    DeclarativeBase,
    dataclass_callable=pydantic.dataclasses.dataclass,
):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

class Transcript(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Transcript"

    id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        "id",
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True,
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
        server_default=sa.text("gen_random_uuid()"),
        default=None,
    )


    # many to one relationship
    owner_id = mapped_column(
        "owner_id",
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        ForeignKey("User.id"),
    )

    owner: Mapped[User] = relationship(
        "User",
        back_populates="transcripts",
        init=False,
    )
```

I use the flag `init=False` as described in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html). However, I still get the following error:

```
web_1  | pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Transcript
web_1  | owner
web_1  |   field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

How can I make aware that owner is a relationship field that is only available after the model was created?

Comment: This is not a solution to this concrete problem with SQLAlchemy, but you maybe want to look into [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) as an alternative that makes all of this arguably much easier.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid SQLModel since people on reddit mention that it's not production ready.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to make Pydantic aware that the owner field is only available after the model is created is to make the owner field optional.

```py
owner: Mapped[Optional[User]] = relationship(
        "User",
        back_populates="transcripts",
        init=False,
        default=None
    )
```